# C# class object overwrite

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am new to OOP, so please take this into consideration. I am puting data that I get from this match into object of a class, but it is done in foreach loop so each time it is called, data inside my object are overwriten, and at the end I would like to have all data in my object. But I only have from last match. How should I do it to avoid this overwriting? Maybe I do it in completely wrong way?

```
foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(new Group[] { match.Groups["C0"], match.Groups["C1"], match.Groups["C2"], match.Groups["C3"], match.Groups["C4"] });

                MyClass sk = new MyClass();

                sk.Category = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
                sk.Device = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
                sk.Data_Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
                sk.Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
                sk.Status = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
            }
```

Comment: What is your `sk` for?

Comment: In the first line of the loop, you are adding a new row to the `dataTable`. You are no overwriting anything here. Then you create a `MyClass` object, fill it, and then **throw it away**.

Comment: It is object of MyClass.

Comment: @user2592968 I can see it is an object of your class but you create it without doing anything with it, that's why I asked for what it was for.

Comment: I think we all understood that, but the question is what are you going to do with it, because as @MD.Unicorn said, you are just throwing it away after putting it's values in it

Comment: Later all data that I put inside my object, I would like to use in another class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a list:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new Group[] { match.Groups["C0"], match.Groups["C1"],
        match.Groups["C2"], match.Groups["C3"], match.Groups["C4"] });

    var sk = new MyClass {
        Category = match.Groups["C0"].ToString(),
        Device = match.Groups["C1"].ToString(),
        Data_Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString(),
        Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString(),
        Status = match.Groups["C4"].ToString()
    };
    list.Add(sk);
}
```

then you have all the items in the list. You could also use LINQ, for example:

```
var items = from match in matches
            select new MyClass {
                Category = match.Groups["C0"].ToString(),
                Device = match.Groups["C1"].ToString(),
                Data_Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString(),
                Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString(),
                Status = match.Groups["C4"].ToString()
            };
```

and iterate over `items`.

Answer (score 3):

The object sk is going out of scope at each iteration of the loop.

try something like this if you want to keep a list of them:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new Group[] { match.Groups["C0"], match.Groups["C1"], match.Groups["C2"], match.Groups["C3"], match.Groups["C4"] });
    MyClass sk = new MyClass();
    sk.Category = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
    sk.Device = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
    sk.Data_Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
    sk.Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
    sk.Status = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
    list.Add(sk);
}
```

Comment: This is also a great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with OOP *per se*. It's more to do with the concept of scope. You're not doing anything with the `sk` object you create. Therefore when your code hits the bottom of the loop body, the `sk` is thrown away.

Perhaps you intended to store references to your objects in a list:

```
//Create a list to store your new shiny sk objects
List<MyClass> sks = new List<MyClass>();

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new Group[] { match.Groups["C0"], match.Groups["C1"], match.Groups["C2"], match.Groups["C3"], match.Groups["C4"] });

    MyClass sk = new MyClass();

    sk.Category = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
    sk.Device = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
    sk.Data_Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
    sk.Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
    sk.Status = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();

    //Add the object to your list
    sks.Add(sk);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a List or something similer:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (var match in matches)
{
       dataTable.Rows.Add(new Group[] { match.Groups["C0"], match.Groups["C1"], match.Groups["C2"], match.Groups["C3"], match.Groups["C4"] });

       MyClass sk = new MyClass();

       sk.Category = match.Groups["C0"].ToString();
       sk.Device = match.Groups["C1"].ToString();
       sk.Data_Type = match.Groups["C2"].ToString();
       sk.Value = match.Groups["C3"].ToString();
       sk.Status = match.Groups["C4"].ToString();
       myList.Add(sk);
}
```

in the end of this code you'll have `myList` with all the items in it and you can go through them with `foreach` for example